# Selenium IDE not able to recognize Checkboxes

Tags: selenium, checkbox, selenium-ide

Recording through Firefox Selenium IDE, not able to capture a checkbox. How do I do that, Below is the property of the checkbox

```
span class="userAgreement">
<input id="ctl_ctl_MainContent_MainContent_Agreement" name="ctl$ctl$MainContent$MainContent$Agreement" 
tabindex="39" type="checkbox">
<label for="ctl_ctl_MainContent_MainContent_Agreement">
```

Comment: Are you recording using Selenium IDE in FF or Chrome? Does Chrome has a IDE for Selenium. Your question needs more details and clarity.

Comment: Hi Naveen it is Selenium IDE in FF. When i record and rererun it fails on the step to check on the checkbox. Thanks!

Comment: Please try with 'runScript' statement with below code. 
var chk  = document.getElementsByClassName('userAgreement');
chk.click();

Comment: I did a runscript command with document.getElementsByClassName('userAgreement'); chk.click(); The command pass thru succesfully without failing. But the check is not working.The field doesnot get checked. Do i have to use Click command separately?

Comment: Yes. In Line 1, document.getElementsByClassName('userAgreement'); in Line 2 chk.click();

Comment: Below is the format i used in Selenium IDE and still i am not able to select the checkbox.                                                                     
runScript                                                                                               var chk = document.getElementsByClassName('userAgreement')

click           chk.click()

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: [error] Element chk.click() not found

Comment: Let me try in my system.

Comment: try this document.getElementById("ctl_ctl_MainContent_MainContent_Agreement").checked = true;

Comment: Perfect! It worked like a charm! Thanks NaveenKumar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code which **checks the checkbox**.

```
document.getElementById("ctl_ctl_MainContent_MainContent_Agr‌​eement").checked = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a click command against the input element

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=ctl_ctl_MainContent_MainContent_Agreement</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks Jsmith but the checkbox is not selected if i use click Id and it thows error message "element ID not found"